# How can i use spread only one time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i improve this code?

```
const { first, second, three, ...list } = minerals
    let newMinerals
    if (currentUnit === 'rd') {
      newMinerals = {
        ...list,
        first: first * 9.8,
        second: second * 9.8,
        three: three * 9.8,
      }
    }
    if (currentUnit === 'ch') {
      newMinerals = {
        ...list,
        first: first / 9.8,
        second: second / 9.8,
        three: three / 9.8,
      }
    }
```

i have two blocks, in one i am multipling and the second i am dividing, how can i improving?

Comment: Should `...list` be `...rest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make an array of properties to change and iterate over it to transform only those properties, using a callback function that changes depending on `currentUnit` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const cb = currentUnit === 'rd'
    ? v => v * 9.8
    : currentUnit === 'ch'
      ? v => v / 9.8
      : null;
const props = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
const newMinerals = !cb ? null : {
    ...minerals,
    ...Object.fromEntries(
        props.map(
            prop => [prop, cb(minerals[prop])]
        )
    )
};
```

If `currentUnit` is always one or the other, it's a lot simpler:

```js
const currentUnit = 'ch';
const minerals = {
  first: 33,
  second: 44,
  third: 55,
  other: 'someother'
};

const cb = currentUnit === 'rd' ? v => v * 9.8 : v => v / 9.8;
const props = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
const newMinerals = {
    ...minerals,
    ...Object.fromEntries(
        props.map(
            prop => [prop, cb(minerals[prop])]
        )
    )
};
console.log(newMinerals);
```

Comment: what do mean 'v'

Comment: `v` is the callback argument to be transformed. Eg `33`, when iterated over, gets passed to the callback and is `v` once.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to me would be to extract the condition and notice that division by `x` is basically multiplication by `1 / x`;
So, you can extract the factor into a variable `factor`, which depending on the unit will either be `9.8` or `1 / 9.8` and multiply it in any case.

Also, this is assuming that there are only two choices of unit. For more than two, you'd want to change the ternary operator to an `if-else-if ladder`

```js
const { first, second, three, ...list } = minerals;
let newMinerals, factor;
factor = currentUnit === 'rd' ? 9.8 : (1/9.8);
  newMinerals = {
    ...list,
    first: first * factor,
    second: second * factor,
    three: three * factor,
  };
```